# Subsample with given mean and std

Tags: sampling

Given an ordered sample set A = {X_1... X_n}, from an unknown non-uniform distribution. Given two params $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Select a subsample set B = {X_k....X_k+m} such that the sample mean of B is $\mu$ and its standard deviation is $\sigma$.

m < n;  Combinations of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ may return no subsample.

The ML application I am looking at is to select a subsample from large training set, at each epoch or iteration of training. The selected subsample has a given mean and standard deviation. As training sample is large, search over all subsamples can not be used. Note that X_i is a scalar, a score is attached to the ith training example. Again this score distribution is unknown, but it is non-uniform. If it was uniform it may suffice to sample from a range (decided by std. dev) around the X_i that is closest to $\mu$.

Comment: why do you want to do this? is it homework ... for a discrete distribution it should be relatively easy, for eg a normal its impossible (though you could get arbitrarily close)

Comment: No its not a homework.. and I know the distribution is non uniform, but I dont know the distribution exactly. I can estimate it using KDE or something.. I am maybe missing something here, which could make this easy.

Comment: Your "subsample," according to your notation, is a *subsequence.*  It is easily found by searching over all such subsequences (a $O(n^2)$ operation).  The application to statistics or machine learning is obscure, because ordinarily we analyze and learn from samples, rather than forcing them to have particular characteristics.  As such, this reads purely like a problem in algorithms and data structures.  If there is an underlying statistical motivation would you mind describing it for us?

Comment: Re "The selected subsample has a given mean and standard deviation."  I would like to push back on that (in the hope it might even solve your problem), because usually a random sample has probabilistic guarantees of lying within bounds for the mean and SD.  *What application do you have that requires you exactly match a given mean and SD, and why?*

Comment: Firstly thanks for being patient with me. I can chose a random subsample : m of the n samples. If m is large the mean/var of B will be close to that of A. If I say, order A,  and select the smallest m values, the mean of B will be smaller than mean of A. If I select the largest m values, the mean/var of B will be greater than mean of A. In either of these ordered cases, var of B will be smaller than var of A. I am trying to find the subsample where the mean/var is close to given mean/var. I dont need to exactly match mean/var.

Comment: You haven't responded to my question, though: *why* do you want to find a "subsample" (subsequence?) that is "close" and exactly what do you mean by "close"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply -- in curriculum learning I want to pick from a training set a set of subsamples. These subsamples should have low mean "score" which is a measure of hardness of each sample. I can do this by ordering samples by score, but I was wondering if I could select a low mean and select samples around it.